# React map function and CSS grid

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

Hy guys,
I'm trying to make a css grid of 5 elements by column with this code in React.
The problem is that css grid considers cartItem as one element of the grid but I'd like to have each div of cartItem (Img, Title, Price, Add, Delete) to be part of the grid. How could I do that ? Thanks

```
const Cartitems = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.Container}>
      <div></div>
      <div>Items</div>
      <div>Price</div>
      <div>Quantity</div>
      <div>Remove</div>
      {props.orders.map((val, i) => {
        return val.num === 0 ? null : (
          <CartItem number={val.num} color={val.color} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const CartItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.Container}>
        <div className={classes.Img}></div>
        <div className={classes.Title}>
          Surf style balance board {props.color}
        </div>
        <div className={classes.Price}>149.00€</div>
        <div className={classes.Add}>
          <div>–</div>
          {props.number}
          <div>+</div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.Delete}>X</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of wrapping the fields of your `CartItem` in a `div` you can use a React Fragment. This will result in all of the children of your cart items sitting adjacent to one another in the DOM:

```
const CartItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
        <div className={classes.Img}></div>
        <div className={classes.Title}>
          Surf style balance board {props.color}
        </div>
        <div className={classes.Price}>149.00€</div>
        <div className={classes.Add}>
          <div>–</div>
          {props.number}
          <div>+</div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.Delete}>X</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Note, instead of using `<>` and `</>` you can also use `<React.Fragment>` and `</React.Fragment>`. Same effect.

Another way to do this is using `display: contents` on the `div` wrapping your `CartItem` children, which will set each child on the parent grid. Unfortunately this has [somewhat limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents) and comes with some [accessibility issues](https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2018-04-21-more-accessible-markup-with-display-contents).

Comment: OK just had the exact same problem and your answer revealed the awesomeness of React Fragment which is just what I need.